# Code First with existing database one to one mapping column error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2014-express

I have an existing database and it contains these two table below:

[image]
[image]

I am trying to create a EF Code First with database  from scratch using fluent mapping.

I have the following dbContext configured:

```
public partial class EFContext : DbContext
{
    public EFContext()
        : base("name=DbContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Log> Log { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Token> Tokens { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LogConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TokenConfiguration());
    }
}

    public partial class Users
    {

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public int Active { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegDate { get; set; }
        public virtual Token Token { get; set; }
     }



     public class Token
     {   
        public string TokenId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string TokenValue { get; set; }
        public int Active { get; set; }
        public DateTime Fecalt { get; set; }
        public virtual Users User { get; set; }
     }

public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Users>
{
    public UserConfiguration() : base()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.UserId);

        Property(e => e.Username)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        Property(e => e.Password)
             .IsUnicode(false)
             .IsRequired()
             .HasMaxLength(50);

        Property(a => a.Active).IsRequired();
        Property(d => d.RegDate).IsRequired();
        HasOptional(u => u.Token).WithRequired(u => u.User);
    }
}

 public class TokenConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<Token>
    {
        public TokenConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(p => p.TokenId);
            Property(p => p.TokenId).HasMaxLength(50);
            Property(p => p.TokenValue).HasColumnName("Token").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(500);
            Property(p => p.Active).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.Fecalt).IsRequired();
            ToTable("Tokens");
        }
    }
```

I have the following exception:

> Invalid column name 'User_UserId'.\r\nInvalid column name
>   'User_UserId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'User_UserId'."

The generated query is this (obviously wrong):

> SELECT 
>       [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
>       [Extent1].[Username] AS [Username], 
>       [Extent1].[Password] AS [Password], 
>       [Extent1].[Active] AS [Active], 
>       [Extent1].[RegDate] AS [RegDate], 
>       [Extent3].[TokenId] AS [TokenId], 
>       [Extent3].[UserId] AS [UserId1], 
>       [Extent3].[Token] AS [Token], 
>       [Extent3].[Active] AS [Active1], 
>       [Extent3].[Fecalt] AS [Fecalt], 
>       [Extent3].[User_UserId] AS [User_UserId]
>       FROM   [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
>       LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Tokens] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[UserId] = [Extent2].[User_UserId]
>       LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Tokens] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[UserId] = [Extent3].[User_UserId]

The query is the following:

```
 var query = from p in efContext.Users
                       .Include( p =>p.Token)
                        select p;
```

The foreign key is not well assigned and the left join is repeated but I dont know how to fix it.

The relationship is in user:

```
 HasOptional(u => u.Token).WithRequired(u => u.User);
```

The registry user is 1 to 0..1, A user token is optional, and the PK/FK relationship is UserID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve is Remove `UserId` property from the class `Token` and configure the relationship inside the `TokenConfiguration` instead of `UserConfiguration` calling MapKey method to specify the foreign key explicitly.

```
public class Token
{
    public string TokenId { get; set; }
    public string TokenValue { get; set; }
    public int Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecalt { get; set; }
    public virtual Users User { get; set; }
}

public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Users>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
        : base()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.UserId);

        Property(e => e.Username)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        Property(e => e.Password)
             .IsUnicode(false)
             .IsRequired()
             .HasMaxLength(50);

        Property(a => a.Active).IsRequired();
        Property(d => d.RegDate).IsRequired();

    }
}

public class TokenConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Token>
{
    public TokenConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.TokenId);
        Property(p => p.TokenId).HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(p => p.TokenValue).HasColumnName("Token").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(500);
        Property(p => p.Active).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.Fecalt).IsRequired();
        HasRequired(d => d.User).WithOptional(d => d.Token).Map(m => m.MapKey("UserId"));
        ToTable("Tokens");
    }
}
```

It worked perfectly with my code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I did already try that looking at the documentation :). I obtain this error: UserId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'UserId' is already defined. I think that is the problem . EF is getting mad with the UserId on different tables and inside the virtual property

Comment: @CarlosLanderas Have you removed property declaration of `UserId` from the model `Token`? I bet you have not removed that property. That's why you are getting that error.

Comment: It is working now. You were right I commented the wrong property in Token class. Thanks dude.